# Windows 10: Task Bar not showing the pinned icons at times

Tags: windows, windows-10, cmd.exe, taskbar, icons

The icons in Task Bar are usually shown the programs pinned. But recently, the icons are not showing up. Sometimes, icons are shown after a restart. Then again, next time icons get disappear.

I tried:

`dism /online /cleanup-image /restorehealth` in **CMD** ( Command Prompt ).

It did not work.

~
**Strange Behaviour** noticed!

This is how the taskbar looks initially on a fresh start of OS.

[image: This is how the taskbar looks initially on a fresh start of OS]

Now, open Google Chrome.

[image: Now, open Google Chrome.]

Right click on Google Chrome icon and select 'Unpin from taskbar'.

[image: Right click on Google Chrome icon and select 'Unpin from taskbar'.]

Surprise! all tray icons are visible now. But then, after Re-start gone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only (default) solution: **Fresh Install of OS**.

**P.S.** I tried different recommendations but none fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I have not encountered this problem before, but here are some general
procedures for solving icon problems :

1. Use [sfc /scannow](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2895-run-sfc-command-windows-10-a.html) to verify system integrity.
   First solve any encountered problems (if any).
2. Use regedit to go to
   `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\TrayNotify`.
   First right-click and Export the whole key for backup, then
   delete both `IconStreams` and `PastIconStream` in the right pane,
   terminating by logoff and logon.
3. [Reset the icon cache database](http://www.windowscentral.com/how-reset-icon-cache-database-windows-10).

Comment: I tried your recommendations but it did not fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Fix: ​
Us​ing​
Windows PowerShell

Take the following steps to use Windows PowerShell to fix the Windows 10 taskbar not working problem.

1. Right-click on Start Menu and choose Command Prompt (Admin)
2. Type PowerShell and press Enter
3. Paste the following command in the PowerShell window and press Enter

   Get-AppXPackage -AllUsers | Foreach {Add-AppxPackage -DisableDevelopmentMode -Register “$($_.InstallLocation)\AppXManifest.xml”}
4. Close PowerShell and navigate to `C:/Users/name/AppData/Local/`
5. Delete TileDataLayer folder

​6. Restart PC!

It should be working fine now.​

Comment: I tried, it worked once and after re-start, icons were gone. Then again, tried once more but it did not fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

If the above recommendations do not help, please check if the same issue occur when logged in through a different user account. This issue could  be caused by corrupted user profile.